# Issue with IF and ELSE

Tags: cobol, mainframe

```
           IF LINE-CTR < PAGE-LIMIT
           ADD 1 TO LINE-CTR.
           WRITE REPORT-RECORD         FROM DETAIL-LINE.
       ELSE    //statement is invalid
           ADD 1 TO PAGE-NUMBER.    //cancel expected after this token
           LINE-CTR EQUALS ZERO.
           MOVE PAGE-NUMBER TO PAGE-NUMBER-OUT.
           WRITE REPORT-RECORD FROM HEADING-LINE-1.
           WRITE AFTER ADVANCING PAGE REPORT-RECORD FROM DETAIL-LINE.   //missing identifier
       END-IF.
```

I'm getting multiple errors and I'm not sure where I'm going wrong here. Please keep it simple with me, I'm not very advanced at COBOL.

Comment: There are a couple of updated answers for you.

Answer (score 4):

```
Get rid of all the full-stops/periods in the code you show.
```

That means get rid of *all* of them.

If your END-IF is the last thing in a paragraph/SECTION, add a new line, and put a full-stop/period in column 12. That satisfies the requirement for a paragraph/SECTION to end with a full-stop/period without attaching it to a line of code.

If you attach a full-stop/period to a line of code (even an END-IF) then when you copy that block of code somewhere else, you have to consider whether to take off the full-stop/period, or leave it. If it is not there, you don't face that decision.

Once you have a bit more experience, you won't be doing that so *you* don't have to think about it, you'll be doing it so that others in your team won't have to think about it.

Originally in COBOL each statement in the PROCEDURE DIVISION was a "sentence", ended with a full-stop/period just like a sentence in a piece of writing.

How did that work for an IF? It meant that everything within the IF did not have a full-stop/period, since a full-stop/period would terminate the IF. Which in turn meant that the line of code

```
MOVE A TO B
```

would have a full-stop/period when it was not in an IF, and no full-stop/period when it was within an IF.

If you were relocating an unconditional MOVE to make it conditional, you had to remember to remove the full-stop/period, else you'd break the existing logic.

With the 1985 COBOL standard this changed. New "scope-delimiters" were added which allowed the closing of all conditional statements and imperative clauses (like `AT END` on a `SEARCH`).

This meant that MOVE A TO B could now be coded in the same way, both within an IF and outside of an IF. Making it much easier to relocate/copy lines of code.

Many people stuck to the old ways, and even if not, there are still programs written from before the 1985 standard, so you will see code with every unconditional line ending with a full-stop/period. That is no longer needed, but don't just change them for the fun of it. If the program already has sleeping dogs, let them lie. But don't write new code in that way.

Here's a an outline PROCEDURE DIVISION for a CALLed program:

```
 PROCEDURE DIVISION            USING parameter-1
                                     parameter-2
                                     .
     PERFORM                         something
     PERFORM                         something-else
     GOBACK
     .
 something.
     some code here
     .
 something-else.
     some more code here
     .
```

The only full-stops/periods are the ones that you see, and you can see them.

Whilst on the subject, look up `NEXT SENTENCE` in the manual. You may find it in existing code, so you need to understand it. It is foolish to use it in new code.

```
IF A EQUAL TO B
    NEXT SENTENCE
ELSE
    MOVE C TO D.
```

Note the full-stop/period which terminates the IF. NEXT SENTENCE is a "secret `GO TO`". It use generates a branch to the code immediately after the next full-stop/period the compiler finds.

IBM allowed its use to continue within an END-IF (the 1985 Standard does not).

```
IF A EQUAL TO B
    NEXT SENTENCE
ELSE
    MOVE C TO D
END-IF
```

That code will hunt for the next full-stop/period, which may only be at the end of the paragraph, making the code which follows the IF conditional - so don't use NEXT SENTENCE. Just use CONTINUE.

```
IF A EQUAL TO B
    CONTINUE
ELSE
    MOVE C TO D
END-IF
```

If you want to know why you'd see that structure anyway, some local site standards forbid the use of negative conditions (yes, really). So to get a negative, you need to code like that...

A tip.

Put your "write a detail line" code into a paragraph/SECTION. In that paragraph/SECTION do the check on the number of lines you've printed.

You then have shortened your code, and made it easier to maintain (if the page-size changes, it is only in one place). Use 88s as well.

This also avoids having to write out the headings when you start the program. Instead, ensure that your line-count is set to a value which indicates "full". This also means you won't get headings when there are no detail lines to print (although many times in this situation you'll have to print a line in the report which says "This report is empty" or words to that effect).

---

Get rid of all the full-stops/periods in the code you show.

A full-stop/period will terminate any conditional/imperative statement, immediately.

Use as few full-stops/periods in the PROCEDURE DIVISION as possible.

This is from a recent answer:

> That is: end of PROCEDURE DIVISION header (after the items on USING if you have one of those); before a paragraph/SECTION; end of a paragraph/SECTION label; end of a paragraph/SECTION; end of the program.
>
> There is some overlap there, as a program does not require that there are paragraphs/SECTIONS within it.

Here's the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27441321/1927206

Comment: So which periods or full-stops should I take oout to make it runnable? I'm still confused

Answer (score 3):

As Bill said, get rid of the full stops. A '.' will end all prior ifs

i.e.

```
 IF blah blah
     IF blah blah again
         IF blah blah !!

            . *> <- this will end all 3 if statements.
```

in your code

```
  IF LINE-CTR < PAGE-LIMIT
      ADD 1 TO LINE-CTR.  *> end of IF because of the '.'
```

Also, what is this line supposed to be ???

```
 LINE-CTR EQUALS ZERO.
```

should it be

```
 Move 0                   to line-ctr
```

---

I **Strongly** suggest only using '.' only when absolutely needed (end of procedures etc). Notice I have no '.' in my logic code:

```
   my-proc.

       IF LINE-CTR < PAGE-LIMIT
           ADD 1                         TO LINE-CTR
           WRITE REPORT-RECORD         FROM DETAIL-LINE
       ELSE   
          ADD 1                          TO PAGE-NUMBER
          Move 0                         to line-ctr      *> ???

          MOVE PAGE-NUMBER               TO PAGE-NUMBER-OUT
          WRITE REPORT-RECORD          FROM HEADING-LINE-1
          WRITE AFTER ADVANCING PAGE 
                REPORT-RECORD          FROM DETAIL-LINE   
      END-IF



      .   *> Full stop by itself at the end
```

Following this code strategy, it easier to spot errors.

In the mainframe ISPF editor, you can use the following commands:

```
X all;F '.' all;f procedure first
```

to show all the lines with a '.' in them. On PC / linux editors you can use regular expressions
to find '.'s that do not have white before them e.g. for JEdit look for:

```
[^\s].
```

This will skip a '.' by itself

```
.
```

but find

```
 LINE-CTR EQUALS ZERO.
```

---

Also line up from's / to's etc, It makes it easier to read. This will make your job easier (and you are more likely to get help that way)

Answer (score 1):

You can NOT use a period (aka "full stop") in open code in modern Cobol without bringing yourself a ton of headaches.  It is a prehistoric construct that only works in very, very, very old style code.  Since you have "End-if", your compiler must bie Cobol-85 complieant, so the rule is NEVER use a period unless you need it.

The only place you need a period in Cobol-85 code is:

-- At the end of a divison or section header, e.g. "procedure division."
 -- At the end of a paragraph name, e.g. "Increment-Page-Number."
 -- At the end of a paragraph, a good trick to make you remember and see this is to use the NOP words "Exit." or "Continue." so that readers will see the period.

Generally, the period (or full stop) is utterly evil and a source of numerous bugs in Cobol code written in the last 30ish years.  You should avoid it if at all possible.

To address your actual question, what you need is something like this:

```
  IF LINE-CTR < PAGE-LIMIT
       ADD 1 TO LINE-CTR
       WRITE REPORT-RECORD FROM DETAIL-LINE
   ELSE
       ADD 1 TO PAGE-NUMBER
       MOVE PAGE-NUMBER TO PAGE-NUMBER-OUT
       WRITE REPORT-RECORD FROM HEADING-LINE-1
       WRITE AFTER ADVANCING PAGE REPORT-RECORD FROM DETAIL-LINE
   END-IF
```

I can't stress strongly enough, don't ever mix "." with "End-*", it is total bad juju.  A ".", or full stop, terminates all open conditions and resets things, weather you like it or not.